# How to make a fixed two line site footer using CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive website footer using CSS.

The responsive website footer requirement (both horizontal lines will have centered links/text, single colored background) is:

```
<link1>-gap-<link2>-gap-<link3>-gap-<link4>
Copyright Text.
```

What CSS do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where exactly the problem is. Simply wrap the footer and give it a `text-align: center;` to center the content. You can use paragraphs or linebreaks (br) to enforce a 2 line style. Of course you can style everything as you want.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

#footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

#footer a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Link 4</a>
  </p>
  <p>Copyright Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to create a gap between the Links line and the Copyright text line below it. Padding messes up entire banner. Is there a way to create a gap between the two lines only?

Comment: yes with `footer p { margin: 5px; }` you rais the gap to 5px between both lines, alternativly raie it to any value you like.

Comment: Ok but this would place margins on the top of the p element also no? I want only a gap between the two <p> lines (one links, one copyright text).

Comment: barely, besides you can lwoer the wrappers padding aswell as going into negative value. coutnering any margins.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<body>
<div style="height:1000px;">
TEXT
</div>
<!-- the following is the footer-->

<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">

<div style="width:24%;display:inline-block;">LINK1</div>
<div style="width:24%;display:inline-block;">LINK2</div>
<div style="width:24%;display:inline-block;">LINK3</div>
<div style="width:24%;display:inline-block;">LINK4</div>

<div style="100%;">Copyright Text</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Enjoy....

Comment: when anwsering you should also explain what you did and how it works so that the others udnerstand it. Providing snippets without any real comment are worthelss as a learnign purpose. Aso if the question is specifically about CSS then you also should sue CSS and not inline style.

Comment: thank you. Will add explanation and be use CSS next time. Thanks